# Identifying features (interior points, connectedness, boundedness, etc.) of a certain subset of the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I have the set {$|z-2+5i|<7,\text{Im}(z)>0$}. I sketched it in Desmos, the overlapping region represents the set. I need to check the properties below of this set.

[image]

Interior points - Is this the set {$|z-2+5i<7$, Im(z) > 0}?

Open - This set is open as every point in the set is an interior point

Boundary points - Just the union of these sets: {$|z-2+5i|<7,Im(z)=0$} $\cup$ {$|z-2+5i|=7,Im(z)>0$}

Closed - Not closed as the set doesn't contain all of its boundary points

Connected - Yes

Simply connected - Yes

Domain - The set is open and connected so it is a domain

Bounded - There exists a positive $R$ such that set is a subset of the set formed by the open ball centered at $0$ with radius $R$, so it is bounded.

Comment: Everything looks good, except the tags.

Comment: @PatrickStewart Forgot about solution-verification, will use from now on. Just making sure, is it correct to assume the boundary points lie on the edge of the shaded region / set, and the interior points are all the points that lie safely inside the shaded region / set?

Comment: What is your doubt?

Comment: @adisnjo That is correct.